# search QStringView in QHash<QString, DataType> without memory allocation?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstring

After parsing of text data I got `QStringView`.
And I need to search if it exists in variable of type `QHash<QString, DataType>`.
Is it possible without conversation of `QStringView` to `QString`,
in other words is it possible without allocation?

May I can use some other `Qt` type for this with similar to `QHash` functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a technique called "transparent maps" that `std::map`, but not `std::unordered_map` or `QHash` supports.  A transparent map allows non-key types to be used to look up elements, so long as they support `==` and they hash equivalently.

As `QHash` doesn't support that you are in trouble.

No `QString` constructor permits it to not copy the bytes into a `QString`.

You could change the `QHash` into a map from a different type.  As it isn't transparent, that type will have to know at runtime if it is owning or not.

In non-Qt C++ I might do

```
using stringish = std::variant<std::string, std::string_view>;
```

then implement a hash function and equality that does proper cross-type checking.

Then

```
std::unordered_map<stringish, DataType, myHash, myEqual> bob
```

would support `bob.find(""sv)` without having to move the string view into a string.

A similar technique should work with `QHash`.

One could even go further and write `QTransparentKey<T>`, that stores either a `T` or function pointers that implement `==` and `hash` in a `T`-compatible way.  Then throw in a type-erasing constructor.

With that, you can have

```
QHash<QTransparentKey<QString>, DataType>
```

just be careful not to create a key entry with an actual string view, which is going to be easy to do and result in segfaults.

Comment: Amusingly enough, this pattern seems slower in debug builds but faster in release